# Overlay on map not drawing properly, is this a cache issue?

Tags: caching, xmlhttprequest, browser-cache, cartodb, har

The site in question is multi.reindicator.com
We have market and neighborhood overlays using Carto, but many users experience an issue where the overlays don't show up properly. This is sometimes resolved when clearing browser cache, but a lot of our members are older and would never be able to figure out how to do that on their own. 
Issue is, I can't figure out how o resolve this problem. I can't find anything in the code that appears to be causing this, so I feel like it may just be the way Carto handles our data.

You can see an example map error here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeBIg.png

Original map looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXpeI.png

I can't think of anything else to try. All browser experience this issue to some extent, and clearing cache does resolve is most of the time, but the browser needs to be quit and reopened.

It uses mapbox for the basemap and Carto for overlays. It "usually" works well but often the overlays are partially rendered. According to the network flow (inspector), some requests response "status: bad -> 'Bad Request'"

Here is a part of the har file:

```
{
        "startedDateTime": "2019-08-20T17:13:04.505Z",
        "time": 121.74399999639718,
        "request": {
          "method": "GET",
          "url": "https://cartocdn-gusc.global.ssl.fastly.net/reindicator/api/v1/map/reindicator@3b077a09@c3615dde7e9d26d95c813667bde38147:1545364448004/1/13/1878/3146.png",
          "httpVersion": "http/1.1",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "Sec-Fetch-Mode",
              "value": "no-cors"
            },
            {
              "name": "Referer",
              "value": "https://multi.reindicator.com/"
            },
            {
              "name": "DNT",
              "value": "1"
            },
            {
              "name": "User-Agent",
              "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36"
            }
          ],
          "queryString": [],
          "cookies": [],
          "headersSize": -1,
          "bodySize": 0
        },
        "response": {
          "status": 400,
          "statusText": "Bad Request",
          "httpVersion": "http/1.1",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
              "value": "*"
            },
            {
              "name": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
              "value": "X-Requested-With, X-Prototype-Version, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization"
            }
          ],
```

As you can see above, the response status is 400.

If anyone has any idea how I can resolve this issue so the users don't experience this partial drawing issue of the overlays and don't need to clear their cache constantly, I'd really appreciate any tips.

Comment: can you tell me a bit more about the carto setup? Are you hosting your own or using the enterprise offering?

Comment: @ShoaibBurq sorry for the late response. The plan my client is using is just under their enterprise plan. I think I was able to mostly resolve this issue by changing the data to "private with link" instead of just "private". Does that sound like it could cause issues in the future?

Comment: If it's enterprise you should contact carto support. I don't think it will make a difference - the problem might reappear. My thoughts were to test by turning the caching off on the server. But that's only possible if you have access to the server.

Comment: You can also try https://getgeodb.com